# Calling Class allocated slot on class-names in Common Lisp

Tags: class, lisp, common-lisp, clos, meta-object-protocol

Is there any way to call a :class allocated slot on the name of a class instead of an instance? Something like: `(class-alloc-slot 'name-of-the-class)`

Answer (score 3):

LispWorks:

```
CL-USER 6 > (defclass foo () ((bar :allocation :class :initform :baz)))
#<STANDARD-CLASS FOO 402005B3CB>

CL-USER 7 > (make-instance 'foo)
#<FOO 4020240C33>

CL-USER 8 > (class-prototype (find-class 'foo))
#<FOO 402005EB73>

CL-USER 9 > (slot-value * 'bar)
:BAZ
```

use CLOSER-MOP for portable MOP features.